# SWT or JFACE Sliders

Tags: java, swt, jface

Does anyone know if there are any "out of the box" (e.g. open source library, in SWT or JFACE directly) ways to create date sliders or sliders with more than one thumb in SWT or JFACE?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You could make a date slider by connecting an SWT Slider with a CLabel to display the date.  However, you would only have one thumb.